# Google Billing crash my app because change screen mode to portrate

Tags: android, in-app-billing, screen-orientation, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have standard billing client with clear architecture, my billing clieant does not know about activity. I Send to billing client activity like a param on his method no more.
My app has screen mode = sensore landscape. I declare that on manifest and on BaseActivity.

**Manifest**

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

**BaseActivity onCreate**

```
   requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
```

When i click on btn for buy some products on my App
I have on some old device good working and on new device crash like **Resources$NotFoundException**. This is due to the fact that no resources were found for the **portrait mode** in which my application is currently located. I cannot understand why on some devices the shopping menu is called in **landscape mode** and on others in **portrait mode**.
I tried to set the Landscape sensor in the client's billing methods, where I transfer the activity parameter, but it did not help. Most likely, you have to go to the library itself

```
com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:6.0.0
```

When I click **BUY** my activity call **onPause** that crash
LOG on picture
[image]

TRY

```
open class BaseApplication : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    }

    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    }

    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    }

    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    }

    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    }

    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    }

    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    }

}
```

***Myaplication***

```
class MyApplication: Application() {

    init {
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: MyApplication? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun getContext(): Context {
            return instance!!.applicationContext
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(BaseApplication())
    }
}
```

but don't help

Comment: Same here. I am a Flutter developer, and this problem is present in the latest version of the Flutter lib

Comment: @Gilian try to use all screen(landscape & portrait) mode when user wants do purchase

Comment: Unfortunately my app is a landscape game. But thanks for the tip, I'll think about how to do it

Comment: @Gilian my game is landscape too but i translate all my screen to default screen orientation and after that I set on manifest landscape orientation.

Comment: @Gilian This problem was connected with finding resources for portrait screen mode. If resource is default this problem does not reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Google bug. Google billing client called on portrait screen mode. After Google billing library update to 6.0.1 version this bug is fixed.
But on this [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#6-0-1) nothing information about this bug.

Comment: I am on 6.0.1, but I am still seeing the same problem on Android 11 and earlier. It does work on Android 14.

Comment: Sometimes this problem reproduce on diferent devices. I Think its bug on Google's side

Comment: 4, 5, 6, 6.0.1 versions has the same bug, as we updated to sdk version 33

Comment: @Tertium this bug reproduce on all versions because its server bug. Its version-independend bug.

Comment: IAB 6 seems to still be severely broken. If you are using Compose, as I am, there is no forcing to portrait. The purchase flow never calls the listener in landscape - only in portrait. This wasn't a problem pre-Compose because at least you could specify your billing screen to be portrait. As Compose is pretty much in one activity it becomes a problem. I guess the work-around is to have the billing in its own activity.